# Change Class Name with jQuery or CSS

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, class, element

So i am trying to change this part of code on my website from saying 'products' to 'shop'

<sub>*Image of the issue highlighted in red:*</sub>

[image]

```
<strong class="breadcrumb_last">Products</strong>
```

The Product text in the breadcrumbs is pulling from the >Products< part as when i change this to 'Shop' it changed this in the breadcrumbs on the site.

I need a way to code this within to my website using CSS or jQuery as this is a wordpress site so it changes

```
<strong class="breadcrumb_last">Products</strong>
```

to

```
<strong class="breadcrumb_last">Shop</strong>
```

any ideas?

Thanks,

Harvey

[[image: JS]]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mOxp.png)[[image: Functions.php]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sWI0.png)

Comment: `document.querySelector('.breadcrumb_last').textContent = 'Shop'`

Comment: Where should i put this within my code? should it go in the php or JS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't** use `$(".breadcrumb_last")` as selector.
On other pages your `.breadcrumb_last` might not contain the desired `Products` text <sup>(See *ex.2*)</sup>

**Instead**, target a parent selector (`#breadcrumbs` in your specific case) and than go for `a, strong` children - in order to make sure you don't change anything else - but the element having the `"Products"` string. Here's how:

```js
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and $ alias secured

  $("#breadcrumbs").find('a, strong').text(function(idx, txt) {
    if (txt === "Products") return "Shop";
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p id="breadcrumbs">

  EXAMPLE 1<br><br>

  <span>
    <span>
      <a href="#!">Home</a>
      &raquo;
      <strong class="breadcrumb_last">Products</strong>
    </span>
  </span>

  <br><br> EXAMPLE 2<br><br>

  <span>
    <span>
      <a href="#!">Home</a>
      &raquo;
      <a href="#!">Products</a> 
      &raquo;
      <strong class="breadcrumb_last">This is a product 1</strong>
    </span>
  </span>

</p>
```

Similarly you've could used `:contains("Products")` but that would also target children like `<a>Dangerous Products</a>` - which is clearly a dangerous thing to do :)

Comment: Hi, This works fine when adding the jQuery in to chrome developer tools but is there somewhere i can see of where its getting this code from as i need to locate the php file that is running this element so i can set it to add in this script.

Comment: I would have though adding it to my functions.php file would have worked but for some reason it just doesent. if not i will give it ago. Not sure if any of you are familiar how scripts get loaded into wordpress as i have dealt with it a few times before myself.

Comment: @Harvey Edited my answer by wrapping tje jQuery code into `jQuery(function($) { /*code here*/ });`. See above. Sometimes I just presume people know how to handle such cases since it's extremely common... Give it a try.

Comment: Hi buljan, I've added code before and was using the (functions($ part but not the jQuery before it, I was adding this at the end so I will give it ago, I got it working in chrome developer and pulling through into my site trough the Wordpress functions.php file it just wasn't making the change so I will give it a try tomorrow and let you know :) cheers

Comment: Hi, I have just added your code into my .js file and it is still not running when refreshing the site and im using incognito and have cleared cache etc. See my JS and functions.php file in my original post i have just edited. The code still works fine in chrome developer snippet though...

Comment: The .js file also shows when i search for it in view page source

Comment: any ideas at all?

Comment: This is what is confusing me, It is working fine in the chrome developer with no errors, i copy the exact code into my .js file and link it to the wordpress function.php file... i open view page source and can see the .js file but it just isn't running. Is there a way to mark it as important or priority like in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

With the existing HTML, I would advice you to use the following code:

```
  $(".breadcrumb_last").text("Shop");
```

However, it would be better if the element have an ID because the chance of collision (updating many elements) is going to be lower. if you decided to give an ID to your element, The following code would be useful.

```
  $("#name-of-element").text("Shop");
```

JSfiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/9k8h53t9/